# Is it possible to cool magnetic dipoles with a magnetic static field?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

Suppose you have a bath of magnetic dipoles, with a common mean rotational kinetic energy.
Now you apply a very strong magnetic field so that the dipoles align with the field, thus "losing" their former kinetic energy.
Does this mean we are cooling the dipoles? Where does the kinetic energy go?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a high magnetic field can massively reduce the entropy of the dipoles for a given temperature. When the dipoles enter a field they become hotter (analogous to a gas when its volume is compressed) so they dissipate heat into their environment (into lattice vibrations and other degrees of freedom). Once the dipoles have returned to thermal equilibrium with their environment they have indeed lost energy.

This principle is used for [magnetic cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration). Once the dipoles are aligned, the field is gradually reduced and the dipoles become extremely cold (like a gas when its volume is decompressed), absorbing heat back from their environment.